# How do I exchange my view in Android on-the-fly?

Tags: android, android-layout

My main layout consists of three views. I will label the View where I don't know how to implement it MysteriousView:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <MysteriousView
        android:id="@+id/MysteriousView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I have three big table views that are defined in their own `.xml` files. Sometimes I want to display `TableView1` in `MysteriousView` and sometimes I want to display `TableView2` in `MysteriousView`.

`TableView1` has 7 rows and 5 columns. `TableView2` has 6 rows and 6 columns.
`TableView3` has 5 rows and 5 columns. I do roughly 50 changes over the lifetime of the activity.

I want to be able to replace them on-the-fly with each other as fast as possible. It would be good if the switching time is less than 100ms.

What's the best way to implement those on-the-fly changes?

Comment: Read about fragments here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is supported in Android by a Fragment.

To quote from the [Android Fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

> You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a
>   multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can
>   think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its
>   own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or
>   remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity"
>   that you can reuse in different activities).

and later:

> When you add a fragment as a part of your activity layout, it lives in
>   a ViewGroup inside the activity's view hierarchy and the fragment
>   defines its own view layout. You can insert a fragment into your
>   activity layout by declaring the fragment in the activity's layout
>   file, as a <fragment> element, or from your application code by adding
>   it to an existing ViewGroup.

Because Fragments are very powerful tools for managing a user interface, using them is more complex than simply swapping a view into an existing ViewGroup, and I can't describe a full solution in a StackOverflow answer, but it is well worth the effort to learn about them ([see the link above](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html))